# Subsetting a string based on particular values

Tags: python

I have a series of strings in a file. Some rows contain "dates" while others contains values. I'm trying to select those rows which contains "string dates" in the format of " 2010-10-01 - 2015-05-01 ".

```
    for row in csvReader:
        if any('-' and '-' in s for s in row): 
            data.append(row)
```

My first few attempts have revolved around grabbing rows which contained one dash or two dashes. However, I keep getting values that I shouldn't, such as below:

```
 0    United States; 2004 - present           None
 1          2004-01-04 - 2004-01-10             23
 2          2004-01-11 - 2004-01-17             23
 3          2004-01-18 - 2004-01-24             23

        617        2015-10-25 - 2015-10-31         24
 618        2015-11-01 - 2015-11-07         25
 619        2015-11-08 - 2015-11-14         26
 620        2015-11-15 - 2015-11-21           
 621                     Spokane WA         20
 622                    New York NY         20
```

So in the above data, I shouldn't get the first row with US and non. Furthermore, I shouldn't get the strings in the final two rows.

Could anyone tell me why my if statement isn't grabbing the right content?

Comment: Please share your file contents

Comment: what do you mean by `'-' and '-' in s for s in row`?

Comment: any rows with - and -, which would suggest that it's a date. if "-" and "-" in row produces an error regarding the axis having 0 elements

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is similar to ishan's solution but a slightly better date check, and it will create the list you want, also by compiling the regex it will be faster over a large data set:

```
import re

datex = re.compile('(19|20)\d\d-(0[1-9]|1[012])-(0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])')

xl = """
0    United States; 2004 - present           None
1          2004-01-04 - 2004-01-10             23
2          2004-01-11 - 2004-01-17             23
3          2004-01-18 - 2004-01-24             23

    617        2015-10-25 - 2015-10-31         24
 618        2015-11-01 - 2015-11-07         25
 619        2015-11-08 - 2015-11-14         26
 620        2015-11-15 - 2015-11-21           
 621                     Spokane WA         20
 622                    New York NY         20
"""

dates = []
for ln in xl.splitlines():
    if datex.search(ln):
       dates.append(ln)
```

just replace the for ln in xl .... with a read from file

Answer (score 1):

hi please try this small solution:

```
import re

mystring = """
0    United States; 2004 - present           None
 1          2004-01-04 - 2004-01-10             23
 2          2004-01-11 - 2004-01-17             23
 3          2004-01-18 - 2004-01-24             23

        617        2015-10-25 - 2015-10-31         24
 618        2015-11-01 - 2015-11-07         25
 619        2015-11-08 - 2015-11-14         26
 620        2015-11-15 - 2015-11-21           
 621                     Spokane WA         20
 622                    New York NY         20
 """
 
result = re.findall(r"(?:[0-9]+-[0-9]+-[0-9]+)+", mystring)
 
for x in result:
    print(x)
```

You can try to run the live code [here](https://repl.it/B1Wb/1)

> To precisely represent your problem
>
> Edit, based on comments below, as you want 2 sets of dates from each line

```
dates = []
for row in csvReader:
    l = re.findall(r"(?:[0-9]+-[0-9]+-[0-9]+)+", row)
    if l:
        dates.append(l)
print(dates)
```

> Output

```
['2004-01-04', '2004-01-10']
['2004-01-11', '2004-01-17']
['2004-01-18', '2004-01-24']
['2015-10-25', '2015-10-31']
['2015-11-01', '2015-11-07']
['2015-11-08', '2015-11-14']
['2015-11-15', '2015-11-21']
```

Comment: that doesnt actually do what he wants - it puts in tuples of dates, not the whole line

Comment: he does what dates extracted, not the whole line
however, what i can do is, `dates.append(re.findall(r"(?:[0-9]+-[0-9]+-[0-9]+)+", row));
print(dates)`

Answer (score 1):

first of all, `'-' and '-' in s for s in row` is not true! for example look at this code:

```
In [1]: x = '-'
In [2]: '-' and '-' in x
Out[2]: True
```

second, to solve your question, I think It's a good choice to use **regex** as follows:

```
>>> m = re.search('[a-z]*(\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2})', 'The date is 2004-01-01') #add each line instead of 2nd argument
>>> m
<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x02229720>
>>> m.group()
'2004-01-01'
```